# Rosbags record parameter server data?

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with some rosbags, `rosbag info` shows that there are some `dynamically reconfigurable` parameters which i want to configure but these `parameters` are not shown when i use `rosparam list`.
In the documentation it was mentioned that `rosbags`  record data on the topics mentioned with `rosbag record`, so my question is-

> Do rosbags record data other than the data they get by subscribing on the topics?

Specific information- I am using Ubuntu 16.04, ROS kinetic, the rosbags were taken from Velodyne VLP-16 LIDAR, I am not sure about the drivers/packages used with VLP-16 since i was only provided with the bags.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325899/rosbags-record-parameter-server-data?/) by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2019-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS bags only record topics; they do not record parameters or service calls.

I'm not aware of any tools that can re-use the dynamic reconfigure topics that may be stored in a bag file.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2